# Comment mettre en valeur plus esthétiquement qu'en gras ?

Tags: discussion, formatting

**Soulignons tout d'abord l'agressivité visuelle du gras massif, épais, disgracieux.**

Ceci étant fait, quelle alternative lui trouver ?

> Dans une [réponse récente](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3282/1514), je m'essayais à l'environnement citation.

Mais cela donne facilement l'impression que le texte ainsi encadré ne fait pas partie du corps du message, et je comprends tout à fait que ça ait fait partie des corrections apportées à mon message.

#### Les (plus petits) titres sont à peine moins agressifs…

*L'italique est bien trop discret.*

- Et les listes à un seul élément… laissent sur sa faim.

***Pour l'instant, le palliatif est l'italique gras, un peu moins choquant. Si vous repérez la question du premier coup d’œil dans ce message, c'est qu'en faire un paragraphe séparé est suffisant¹.***

¹  <sub>Tout du moins dans un texte aussi lourdement formaté que cette question.</sub>

---

**tl;dr :**  The bold font doesn't look very good for whole sentences, but what else can we use for emphasis rather than quotes?

Comment: Related question ? : http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/71/nutilisez-pas-les-blocs-de-code-pour-les-citations-do-not-use-code-blocks-for?

Answer (score 3):

Tout d'abord un argument contre les boîtes, colorées ou pas, qui s'appellent de leur joli nom *blockquotes*. Leur sémantique est la même que celle des guillemets, elles permettent typiquement de citer un texte, de faire référence à un passage ou à un extrait, ou bien d'introduire un exemple. Il faut les privilégier lorsque le texte cité est long ou lorsqu'il est avantageux de l'aligner avec d'autres extraits. Voici la façon dont ces boîtes sont affichées par défaut avec la version « mobile » du site:

[image: affichage sur téléphone portable]

Vous remarquerez que le texte est plus petit et que la couleur de fond n'est pas différenciée. Cela convient parfaitement pour une citation, mais si l'intention était de mettre la phrase en valeur, je crois que pour le coup, c'est raté. Le lecteur va devoir réfléchir un bout de temps avant de comprendre que le texte cité est en fait un prolongement en continuité avec le texte principal.
On n'utilise pas les guillemets pour mettre en valeur, et il ne faut donc pas utiliser les blockquotes pour cela non plus.

Pour les mêmes raisons, utiliser abusivement le format des titres n'est pas une solution acceptable.

J'aurais aussi tendance à éviter l'italique car l'utiliser pour une phrase entière c'est rendre difficile son utilisation à l’intérieur même de cette phrase. (Et tout le monde aura remarqué que sur ce site celui-ci est plus qu'indispensable pour mentionner des mots ou des expressions).

Quant au gras (utilisé avec parcimonie) je ne vois rien à lui reprocher, si ce n'est l'esthétique malheureuse qu'il possède *actuellement*. Il ne tient qu'à nous de nous manifester pour qu'il soit rendu plus léger lorsque le site passera en version finale (ou même avant).

Mais en conclusion, je tiens à souligner que le plus efficace et le plus élégant c'est avant tout d'employer les mots qui conviennent pour mettre quelque chose en valeur. Il est rarement nécessaire de recourir à du formatage superflu, et si malgré tout il fallait y recourir, la technique simple consistant à énoncer un point ou une question importante à l’intérieur d'un paragraphe court et concis est souvent amplement suffisante.

Comment: J'ai tendance à ne pas être d'accord avec la conclusion, surtout au regard de [ce genre de demandes](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/276/asnwers-are-too-long) : tout ce qui facilite le repérage rapide de l'information essentielle est bon à prendre, d'après moi. Cela mis à part, tout à fait d'accord. Est-ce qu'on pourait avoir un aperçu qui corresponde au site principal, plutôt qu'à meta, par contre ? (Notamment pour les couleurs.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Eurêka j'ai trouvé :-)

---

[image]

... Il est malheureusement très difficile de mettre cette idée d'image en oeuvre ; les abus peuvent être nombreux, et elle n'est pas très pratique à réaliser.

Il faudrait poser la question aux designers de stackexchange, de façon à établir un markdown spécial esthétique, surtout que l'esthétique est une question absolument fondamentale.

Comment: Il manque le champ `insert text here` :·p

Comment: Pourquoi y at-il une image de Durga ici?

Comment: Il y a une image de Durga pour mettre en valeur ma réponse de façon esthétique. Ça marche bien, hein ?  Si vous voulez... [Autres images de Durga](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Durga) - [Et cette image ci](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Durga_Burdwan_03_10_2011.JPG) (sauf que je ne connais rien à Durga, c'était juste l'image du jour d'hier sur Wikimedia Commons... on peut employer d'autres images que de Durga... de la tour Eiffel, par exemple).

Comment: J'aime vraiment l'idée, en fait. Voir [ici](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/) pour une démonstration. J'ai essayé rapidement de trouver des bordures pour texte, sans trop de succès, malheureusement :/

Comment: J'ai édité mon idée pour montrer qu'elle pouvait être un peu plus discrète, et que, à mon avis, elle ne pouvait être utile qu'après réflexion :-)

Comment: Est-ce que ça prend de vérifier que les images sont libres de droits, licence, etc., par exemple ? J'ai failli *feature* Durga quand j'ai posé ma [Q/A](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/quand-ecrire-quant) (à la place du gras sur *en règle générale*), mais je me dis que l'idée n'est effectivement peut-être pas encore tout à fait au point.

Comment: Oui le design est qqchose de difficile. Les images que j'ai mises viennent de [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org) donc normalement c'est bon au niveau des droits à ce que j'ai compris, mais ce genre de choses complique encore la situation. Pour moi, la solution passe forcément par ceux qui font le design du site.

Comment: This is said to be [a good way to earn rep fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/197593). Also bunnies are cute.